# How to implement Paypal checkout with credit or debit card option with only business email address

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to implement the paypal new checkout which provide pay by credit or debit option without having an Paypal account.

I need one time payment as well as subscription payment (monthly/weekly/daily). I have only Paypal business email address for implementation.

Please let know if there is any way to implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create non-smart HTML-only (no JS) buttons at https://www.paypal.com/buttons

For the newer smart buttons, you need to log into the account that will be receiving the payments in order to generate a button, especially in the case of subscriptions.

Comment: In these buttons i need to set the amount manually. It should have the option to set it by subscription.

Comment: For the non-smart buttons in Step II you can uncheck the option to save the button at PayPal, and when the code is generated click to remove the code protection

Comment: For the smart buttons in addition to the `plan_id` you will need to pass a `plan` with details to override whatever you want to override, particularly the `billing_cycles` sub object with its `pricing_scheme`.  Use your existing plan's as a base. https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body